# Get day id from datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I would like to be able to get a day 'id' from bootstrap datepicker. For example, if the user inputs `16/07/2018` which corresponds to a Monday, I want to get `1` as a result.

Edit : note that what I'm trying to achieve here isn't displaying the name of the day in the corresponding language. I really just want the `int` from the `getDay()` method.

Comment: Use `Date.getDay()` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display Day of the Week after Date with bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240735/display-day-of-the-week-after-date-with-bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: Harunur Rashid gave me exactly what I was looking for. The question Pardeep Dhingra linked contained the answer as well, thanks to both of you. I can mark one of your answers as valid if you post it down below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) to get the weekday in the current language.

```
var options = { weekday: 'short'};
var weekday = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, options).format(date);
```

A complete list of weekday formats can be found at the link above. Undefined in the first parameter causes the browser to use it's current language.